# How to remove multiple selected items in listbox in tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I want to be able to delete all selected items when I use selectmode=MULTIPLE.
I have tried to delete but it only deletes the item that was selected last. Is there any way to delete **all** of the items.

Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

def abc():
    listbox.delete(ACTIVE)

def xyz():
    z=listbox.get(0, END)
    print (z)

master = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(master,orient=VERTICAL)
listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
b = Button(master, text="delete", command=abc)
b.pack(side=RIGHT)
b2 = Button(master, text="save", command=xyz)
b2.pack(side=RIGHT)
scrollbar.pack(side= RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT)

for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 11):

To get all selected items instead of only the last one, you can use `listbox.curselection()` and then delete them one by one, starting from the last one so that the indexes of the other ones are not modified by the deletion.

```
def abc():
    sel = listbox.curselection()
    for index in sel[::-1]:
        listbox.delete(index)
```

By the way, I advise you to give meaningful names to your functions (like "delete" instead of "abc").

Answer (score 4):

Only half of selected items are deleted.

I think the index is recreated after each delete so items reassigned to a deleted index will not be deleted.

item index: 0,1,2,3 after deleting 0 becomes 0,1,2 then it thinks that 0 is already deleted so deletes 1. After deleting 1 the index is 0,1 - which are both already deleted so nothing more to delete.

ANSWER: The trick is to delete the selected items in reverse order so that items earlier in the list are not reindexed by delete:

```
def call_delete():
    selection = listBox.curselection()
    for i in reversed(selection):
        listBox.delete(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove selected items of lsbox using python build-in revered method:

```
def delete_task():
    selections = lsbox.curselection()
    for selection in reversed(selections):
        lsbox.delete(selection)
```

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT** The better answer is not this one, but leaving this here for the documentation and the url. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44818820/1141389

Take a look [here for more info on Listbox wiget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)

You can clear the whole listbox with

```
listbox.delete(0, END)
```

If you only want the selected items deleted, I *think* you could do something like the following:

```
def abc():
    items = map(int, listbox.curselection())
    for item in items:
        listbox.delete(item)
```

but note that I cannot test this currently. Try the above and checkout the website, that should get you on the right track.

Comment: I have tested your answer and if you select the items "one", 'three", "five" and click on "delete", it does not delete the right items.

Comment: did you replace your whole `abc` method with mine? you shouldn't have "one", etc. in items

Comment: Yes, I replaced the `abc` method in the OP's code with yours and I clicked on "one", 'three", "five" to select them (that's what I meant in my previous comment). Then I clicked on "delete" and it deleted items "one" and "four".

Comment: Ah. Like I said, I can't test currently. I might be able to later, but was hoping the link would give you what you need.

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that by deleting the first item, you change the indexes of the other items. To avoid that, you can iterate over items starting from the end (like I did in my answer).

Comment: Whoops, sorry, didn't check, thought you were OP. Upvoted your answer instead